# Whitelabel Error Page instead of missing required parameter

Tags: java, spring, rest, http-status-code-400

I have a `GET /object` call with required parameter `id`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/object"}, produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getObject(@RequestParam(required = true) String id, HttpServletRequest request) {

    // do stuff
    ...

    // Send message
    return json;
}
```

When it's called without the parameter `id` my spring application throws a :
`Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'id' is not present]` but the caller recieves a `Whitelabel Error Page` with a `400` status with no explanation on the missing parameter...

Is there a way to return to the caller what paramter is missing ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom Error Page, which would describe the exceptions you declare. See here: https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring